# NestJS - inject service into typeorm migration

Tags: dependency-injection, migration, nestjs, typeorm

I would like to inject a service into a typeorm migration, so that I can perform data migration based on some logic within a service:

```js
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { MyService } from '../../services/MyService.service';
import { MyEntity } from '../../entities/MyEntity.entity';

export class MyEntityMigration12345678
  implements MigrationInterface
{
  name = 'MyEntityMigration12345678';

  constructor(
    private readonly myService: MyService,
  ) {}

  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    const myEntityRepository: Repository<MyEntity> =
      queryRunner.connection.getRepository<MyEntity>(MyEntity);

    const entities = await myEntityRepository.findBy({
      myColumn: '',
    });

    for (const entity of entities) {
      const columnValue = this.myService.getColumnValue(myEntity.id);
      await myEntityRepository.save({
        ...entity,
        myColumn: columnValue,
      });
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

Nevertheless

- `myService` is `undefined`, and
- `myEntityRepository.findBy(.)` gets stuck.

How can I do a migration based on business logic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to write whatever query `myService.getColumn` value does inside your migration. If you're hell bent on using Nest's DI inside your migration then you could do something like this:

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { AppModule } from '../../app.module'; // assumed path
import { MyService } from '../../services/MyService.service';
import { MyEntity } from '../../entities/MyEntity.entity';

export class MyEntityMigration12345678
  implements MigrationInterface
{
  name = 'MyEntityMigration12345678';

  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    const myEntityRepository: Repository<MyEntity> =
      queryRunner.connection.getRepository<MyEntity>(MyEntity);

    const entities = await myEntityRepository.findBy({
      myColumn: '',
    });
    const appCtx = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);
    const myService = app.get(MyService, { strict: false });
    for (const entity of entities) {
      const columnValue = myService.getColumnValue(myEntity.id);
      await myEntityRepository.save({
        ...entity,
        myColumn: columnValue,
      });
    }
    await app.close();
  }

  // ...
}
```

You can't use injection inside the migration because the class itself is managed by TypeORM. You can, as shown above, create a `NestApplicationContext` instance and get the `MyService` instance from that. This only works, by the way, if `MyService` is `REQUEST` scoped

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It says `EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "MyEntity" was found.`

Comment: Found my error. I didn't specify the entities in my DataSource. Works now. Thanks!